# LC circuit in spring system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-circuits, capacitance, spring, inductance

We have a setup of a metal spring with a mass. This would oscillate nicely. Additionally, an inductor with a capacitor also oscillates nicely. If we were to combine these two setups, where the mass is a battery, connected to the spring (inductor) and a capacitor, what happens? In other words, how do the electrical and mechanical oscillations interact with each other?

If we have the physical measurements of the spring (num of turns, spring constant, unstretched length), the battery (emf and mass), can we find a closed formula for the resulting motion and current of the system?

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have taken the liberty to [resize your image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/) to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you wish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually model mechanical system as electrical circuits. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies

A common example for circuits that use both mechanical and electrical part. See for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Transducers_-_Loudspeaker

However, this wouldn't make sense in your example since mechanical and electrical domain don't interact. For the electrical side it doesn't matter if the coil is a spring or a regular inductor and for the mechanical side it doesn't matter whether the mass is a battery or just a chunk of wood.

Answer (score 0):

The statement *"a metal spring with a mass...would oscillate nicely. Additionally, an inductor with a capacitor also oscillates nicely."* conflates the mechanical and electrical domains.

The *position* (and speed, etc.) of a hanging spring oscillates; the *voltage* (and current, etc.) of an LC circuit also oscillates.  It's not clear if you mean to use one or the other as an analogy here or if you mean to describe literal components.

Thus, the question *"If we were to combine these two setups, where the mass is a battery, connected to the spring (inductor) and a capacitor, what happens?"* is somewhat unclear; are you interested in the mechanical or electrical response? Oscillation could occur in both contexts, potentially with some degree of coupling (e.g., the electrical inductance of a spring can change as the spring contracts or elongates).

Comment: Yes, sorry that I worded the question poorly. The spring connected to the voltage source is the system. It is true that as the spring changes length, the inductance is affected as well. I wanted to find the degree of coupling and how the system functions as the spring changes length. Depending on the periods of both the LC and spring, how do these oscillations 'add' and affect each other?